# Severe network performance drop after upgrade from win8.1 pro to win8.1 enterprise

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I upgraded to win 8.1 enterprise from 8.1 pro a few days ago, and my network performance has gone down drastically. Web browsing is barely tolerable, and launching a bittorent client crashes the network for the whole house.

How can I diagnose and resolve this issue?

Comment: You sure this isn't a internet service problem?  There is no difference between pro and enterprise that would explain your problem

Comment: No, its local to the system in question. Other systems on the network have exponentially better ping

Comment: Are you hard-wired? Are you on wireless? Are there other users on your network? Is your machine infected with viruses? What do you mean by `crashes the network for the whole house.`? Torrenting usually requires persistent connections to many other machines so yes this behavior does have side-effects even if you are torrenting at half-capacity. Are the other systems on the network doing a lot of network activity? If 3 netflix movies are running then: yes, your symptoms sound accurate.

Comment: Wireless, have yet to attempt deep virus scan, but this is a fresh install.  Crashes the network means everybody loses web access. Even without torrent, performance (and ping) is extremely bad. Moreover, I had bt running pretty much continuously before the upgrade and had no problems.

Comment: It's not a fresh installation if you migrated from pro to enterprise...

Comment: I didnt migrate. I formatted